# How to continue a loop while waiting for user input?

Tags: python

In my program I want it to await user input, while continuing the loop. because in the loop an audio clip plays (a ding sound) to remind me to manually input what I cant automate on my pc.

```
import audio
import time
wait_for_user = input('WAITING FOR INPUT')

while(wait_for_user != 'yes'):
   wait_for_user = input('WAITING FOR INPUT')
   audio(driver,'ding.mp3')
   time.sleep(3)
```

Obviously it just stops at `wait_for_user` and doesn't continue, I just can't seem to even conceive of how to go about this.

Comment: Check out Python [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) module (coroutines in particular).

Comment: thanks :) this is probably the way forward.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Unix-like OS, you can use `select` to wait for IO:

```py
import select

user_input = None
while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    input_ready, _, _ = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
    for sender in input_ready:
        if sender == sys.stdin:
            user_input = input()
    if user_input is None:
      # play audio
    else:
      # user input done
      break:
```

Comment: thanks alot. its probably correct, but i get this error: '[WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket'

Comment: Ouch. You're on Windows! I guess this doesn't work on Windows since `select` is a POSIX API.

Comment: damn, have you got a windows solution?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way with `asyncio` as our friend mentioned in comments below your post. But for now, I have none.